# What's the purpose of pattern matching in this case in scala？

Tags: scala, functional-programming

```scala
list = List((1,2), (3,4))
swapped_list = list.map{case (a, b) => (b, a)}
```

I wonder the purpose of this `case`.
Is there a design principle behind this or what?

Under some similar questions, some explain it as the application of partial function. But why on earth should we use partial function even if they are right?

IMO, the most natural form to write this is like below

```scala
swapped_list = list.map(x => (x._2, x._1))
```

Comment: The best would be `list.map((a, b) => (b, a))` but in Scala 2 it's illegal so we have to write `case`.

Comment: @DmytroMitin At least there should be a reason to design the language in this way...idk

Comment: The purpose is to make the code more readable by giving a more precise name to each element in the tuple _(however in this case it is not that important since `a` & `b` are still very simple names; but you may use it for something like `name` & `age` or `record` & `idx`)_. - Also, pattern matching can be nested, so if some element of the tuple is another tuple or a case class, you can keep deconstructing it. - In any case, this is really subjective, if you prefer the other option go for it, I would just say that you are the first person I know that prefers to use the tuple index over `case`

Comment: `list` has type `List[Tuple2[Int, Int]]`, and `(a, b) => (b, a)` has type `Function2[Int, Int, Tuple2[Int, Int]]` and not `Function1[Tuple2[Int, Int], Tuple2[Int, Int]]`.

Comment: This is not language design, this is an style decision made by some programmer. You are not forced to use pattern matching.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Well, not-automatic wrapping-unwrapping tuples is a language design.

Comment: @DmytroMitin yeah, I mean about the use of pattern matching over just accessing the tuple elements.

Comment: Do you see the irony of claiming that using numeric indices instead of semantic names is "more natural", then having to go back and edit your question because you actually couldn't get those numeric indices straight?

Comment: If we define implicit conversion `implicit def wrapTuple[A, B, C](f: (A, B) => C): ((A, B)) => C = f.tupled` we can write `list.map((a: Int, b: Int) => (b, a))`. Unfortunately we can't just remove parameter types.

Comment: More general approach `implicit def wrapTuple[F, L <: HList, Out, T](f: F)(implicit fnToProduct: shapeless.ops.function.FnToProduct.Aux[F, L => Out], generic: shapeless.Generic.Aux[T, L]): T => Out = t => fnToProduct(f)(generic.to(t))`.

Comment: Or, in this particular case, just `list.map(_.swap)`.

Answer (score 7):

> What's the purpose of pattern matching in this case in scala?

It's not *exactly* pattern matching. It is what the [Scala Language Specification](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/) calls a [*Pattern Matching Anonymous Function*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-matching-anonymous-functions) but in the community is typically referred to as a *partial function literal*.

A *Pattern Matching Anonymous Function* consists of a block with several `case`s but no `match` expression. Depending on the expected result type, it defines either a `Function` or a `PartialFunction`. The exact translation will be as-if you wrote a `Function` or `PartialFunction` with a Pattern Matching `match` Expression inside, i.e. the code in the question is equivalent to

```scala
swapped_list = list.map(x => x match { case (a, b) => (b, a) })
```

which is in turn equivalent to this:

```scala
swapped_list = list.map(
  new scala.Function2[Tuple2[Int, Int], Tuple2[Int, Int]] {
    def apply(x: Tuple2[Int, Int]): Tuple2[Int, Int] = x match {
      case (a, b) => new Tuple2[Int, Int](b, a) 
    }
  }
)
```

Because `List.map` expects a `Function`. If `List.map` expected a `PartialFunction`, it would instead be translated like this:

```scala
swapped_list = list.map(
  new scala.PartialFunction2[Tuple2[Int, Int], Tuple2[Int, Int]] {
    def apply(x: Tuple2[Int, Int]): Tuple2[Int, Int] = x match {
      case (a, b) => new Tuple2[Int, Int](b, a) 
    }

    def isDefinedAt(x: Tuple2[Int, Int]): Boolean = x match {
      case (a, b) => true
      case _ => false
    }
  }
)
```

> I wonder the purpose of this `case`.

That's how you write a *Pattern Matching Anonymous Function*. The purpose of the `case` here is the same as the purpose of the `"` in a string literal or the purpose of the `class` in a class declaration, it's simply the syntax for writing a partial function.

> Is there a design principle behind this or what?

It's not clear what you mean by that. The parser needs to have some way of recognizing language constructs, keywords like `case` are one of many possible ways to achieve that.

> Under some similar questions, some explain it as the application of partial function.

That's wrong. It's not *applying*, and it's not a *partial* function. It is *defining* a *function*. `List.map` is the one that *applies* the function in this case.

> But why on earth should we use partial function even if they are right?

Why not?

Writing it in this way allows you to give intention-revealing semantic names to the elements of the tuple. `a` and `b` may not be the *best* names in the history of programming (I would have called them `first` and `second` instead), but they sure beat `x._1` and `x._2`.

> IMO, the most natural form to write this is like below
>
> ```scala
> swapped_list = list.map(x => (x._2, x._1))
> ```

The important part of your statement is this:

> IMO

That is *your* opinion. Clearly, the author of the code you posted has a different opinion. Their opinion is just as valid as yours.

From a short, completely non-scientific, biased, non-representative survey of a couple of different snippets of code I pulled off the web, it looks like almost 100% of my sample set disagree with your opinion, and prefer to be able to give intention-revealing semantic names to the tuple elements.

In fact, before your edit, you *yourself* had written this:

> IMO, the most natural form to write this is like below
>
> ```scala
> swapped_list = list.map(x => (x._1, x._2))
> ```

So, you had actually swapped the indices without noticing. This would have been easier to spot with this:

```scala
swapped_list = list.map { case (a, b) => (b, a) }
swapped_list = list.map { case (a, b) => (a, b) }
```

and even better with this:

```scala
swapped_list = list.map { case (first, second) => (second, first) }
swapped_list = list.map { case (first, second) => (first, second) }
```

Of course, the *best* way to write this would be:

```scala
swapped_list = list.map(_.swap)
```

Using the [`scala.Tuple2.swap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Tuple2.html#swap:(T2,T1)) method.